# Why must I keep declaring the same required but not implemented initializer for init(coder aDecoder) for my programatic UIViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, designated-initializer

Perhaps it is just me, but I find certain aspects of swift... obtuse to say the least.

I  don't use Interface Builder most of the time because I like using `PureLayout`. So I was hoping to make a `UIViewController` subclass, say `PureViewController`, that had a handy `init` without parameters:

```
class PureViewController : UIViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

But this is not okay, for XCode tells me I must also implement `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. Okay, that's fine! That's why I made this class - so I don't have to do this again for subclasses.

```
class PureViewController : UIViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Ok, now here's what I don't get.

I define a subclass, `SomePureViewController : PureViewController`, with an initializer `init(viewModel:ICrackersViewModel)`...

```
class SomePureViewController : PureViewController {

    init(viewModel:ICrackersViewModel) {
        super.init()
    }

}
```

But it **STILL** wants me to define the same stupid initializer till kingdom come!

```
class SomePureViewController : PureViewController {

    init(viewModel:ICrackersViewModel) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Now I understand the idea - there is no `init(decoder)` in my subclass, even though it is defined in its parent class.

Maybe I've always dealt with this issue with `UIViewController` and never noticed it before.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there something I am doing wrong to cause this behavior?
2. Is there any way outside of inheritance that I can avoid repeating myself?
3. Are there plans to any plans to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that one can initialize a possibly derived class just by knowing the base type.

Lets assume a base class

```
class Base {
    let value: Int

    required init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

and a function

```
func instantiateWith5(cls: Base.Type) -> Base {
    return cls.init(value: 5)
}
```

then we can do

```
let object = instantiateWith5(Base.self)
```

Now if someone defines a derived class

```
class Derived: Base {
    let otherValue: Int

    init() {
        otherValue = 1
        super.init(value: 1)
    }

    required init(value: Int) {
        fatalError("init(value:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

We are at least able to call

```
let object2 = instantiateWith5(Derived.self)
```

violating LSP, but that's a problem of your code, not the language.

Swift has to guarantee that initializers leave your objects in a initialized state, even when they are derived from a base object, so I guess changing that would be a bad thing. If you like to define a UIViewController that is not deserializable and thereby violating LSP it's your decision - but don't expect the language to support you in this.

Comment: Good answer. I'm going to need to play around with it some more to really "get it" but I still feel like this is a problem only for swift for some reason. Or rather, maybe it's that `required` is a feature only swift has.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is swift issue and there is no way how to avoid this. We all hate this empty - fatal error initializer.

Answer (score 1):

As the initialiser is marked with the `required` keyword, all subclasses must implement that initialiser and they must also specify `required` on their implementation so that *their* subclasses are also required to implement it.

> **Required Initializers**
>
> Write the required modifier before the
>   definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of
>   the class must implement that initializer
>
> You must also write the required modifier before every subclass implementation of a required initializer, to indicate that the initializer requirement applies to further subclasses in the chain.”

This has been part of the Swift language since 1.0 and it is unlikely to change.

The issue is actually to do with the use of the `required` keyword in the UIViewController class definition. In theory this could be changed, but again I think it is unlikely.